# Selective .js cache on nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, cache

I have one .js file that can't be cached by the browser. Because of this file, I have this in my nginx configuration file:

```
location ~* .(js)$ {
expires epoch; log_not_found off; access_log off;
}
```

However, this is terrible: because of one file, all the others .js files don't be cached by the browser. There are .js files in subdomains that may be cached. So, here's what I can do:

• Disallow all .js my files on my main public folder be cached and let all my files on subfolders be cached.

How can I make this configuration in nginx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location = /dont/cache/this.js {
    expires epoch;
}

location ~* \.js$ {
    expires max;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @michael-hampton

If I use "/dont/cache/{ ", the result will be the same, yeah? The .js inside folder /dont/cache won't be cached?

Comment: Seems unlikely. Update your question with your actual nginx config and details on what you are trying to do.